# Caching and serving GZipped JSON directly to response

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, redis

I'm caching JSON strings in Redis via Stackexchange.Redis in ASP.NET MVC

I am going go GZip the strings before storing them in the Redis cache to help improve performance.

Instead of un-compressing the JSON strings after retrieving them from the cache only to let them become GZipped again when being sent to the browser, would it be possible not leave the JSON string compressed and serve it directly to the browser?

The following attempt to serve a GZipped string directly to the browser doesn't work.

```
  string uncompressed = "Test text";
  string compressed = GZipHelper.Compress(uncompressed);                        
  Response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
  return this.Content(compressed, "application/json");
```

Comment: Why don't you set output cache on the action that returns those jsons. You can make it VaryByParam in case you need it

Comment: @AlexArt. That's a good point. I wasn't using output cache as I had problems with error pages getting cached and served up later. I've found now that you can prevent this, and output cache looks like the best options. I think there are some cases where being able to do the above could be useful so I'll leave the question here.